# How to format a Date with Amscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, timezone

While setting an hour in Sales, it seems the Amscript in Marketing Cloud I am using is getting minus one hour. I set 14.00 in Sales and I get 13:00 in Marketing Cloud.

I am trying to use zzz or xxx but I don´t know how to remove the difference.

```
%%=FormatDate(@FechaCita, "","HH:mm:zzz", "es-ES")=%%
```

How can I get the right time?

Comment: To verify, you are saying that when you format the date, the time it is returning is 1 hour less than what you have in your original? FormatDate() should not cause any changes to the data you provide except for the way it is displayed.  I would verify that the transition from SalesCloud to Marketing Cloud does not cause the change - as that is more likely the suspect for the change in displayed time.

Answer (score 2):

To format a date and return it in the specified format,

```
%%=Format("2017-10-05 13:21:34.567890", "MMM dd, yyyy", "HH:mm:ss.tt", "en-US")=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with formating, it's time-zone difference- Sales Cloud returns data in GMT, you are GMT+1.

Are you retrieving your date with Ampscript [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) or from a data extension? If you use RetrieveSalesforceObjects, it containes timezone info as well, so you can just wrap your date in [SystemDateToLocalDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm?search_text=SystemDate) to return it in your user selected timezone.

```
%%=SystemDateToLocalDate(@FechaCita)=%%
```

If you get data from data extension you can just simply add one hour with [DateAdd()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateAdd.htm) but it might produce incorrect results sometimes (depending on summer/winter time changes):

```
%%=DateAdd(@FechaCita, '1','H')=%%
```

Comment: I used the second option from @Mateusz and it worked smooths. thanks a lot!

Comment: the end formula was:

Answer (score 1):

the final formula:

```
%%[set @FechaCita = DateAdd(Lead:Date_first_visit__c, '1','H')]%%

%%=FormatDate(@FechaCita, "DD", "", "es-ES")=%% 
de %%=FormatDate(@FechaCita, "MMMMM","", "es-ES")=%% %%=FormatDate(@FechaCita, "","HH:mm", "es-ES")=%%  %%Lead:Centro_primera_visita__r:Name%%.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the date elements and then add one hour like this:

```
SET @HH = FormatDate(NOW(), "","HH", "es-ES")
SET @mm = FormatDate(NOW(), "","mm", "es-ES")
SET @zzz = FormatDate(NOW(), "","zzz", "es-ES")
SET @HH_fixed = Add(@HH, "1")
```

And you can show it like that:

```
%%=v(@HH_fixed)=%%%%=v(":")=%%%%=v(@mm)=%%%%=v(":")=%%%%=v(@zzz)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find here the [AMPscript Date and Time Formatting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm). It may help you.